# In Redshift, how to COPY dates like 0000-00-00 00:00:00?

Tags: datetime, amazon-redshift

I have some datetimes that are 0000-00-00 00:00:00, and I want to copy them into Redshift. It'd probably be OK to replace that with null. Is there some argument to the COPY command I can use to say that 0000-00-00 00:00:00 dates are acceptable? Right now, it errors saying it is an invalid date when I run a COPY.

Comment: [Christian Carey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15576453) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66991278) saying "Use acceptanydate in the COPY command - [COPY - Data conversion parameters - acceptanydate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-acceptanydate)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't copy these into timestamp or date fields since it's just not a valid date.  If you can't default them in whatever extract you're using (MySQL allows these values for instance, so sometimes I use an IF statement to default them to some other value such as 1971-01-01 00:00:00), I recommend using a staging table that uses varchar types instead.  This will allow the COPY to complete, then you can use a DECODE function to default them to a valid value as you move the data into your target table.